# Will readers easily understand the following sentence, or should I express it differently?

Tags: grammar, expressions, commas

> What happened, happened, and the past cannot be changed.

Are the commas correctly used? Also, I'm concerned some readers will believe I mistakenly typed the word "happened" twice. Is there a better way to express this, or is it fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a couple of different sources, your phrase is completely acceptable. However, it would create a greater impact on the readers if you divided the above example into two sentences.

> "*What happened, happened. The past cannot be changed.*"

The fact that you're using a comma to separate the two "*happened*"'s, makes it all the more clear to the reader that it was intentional.

Saying, "*what happened happened*" without the comma feels grammatically wrong in my opinion. In this case, as you said, readers might believe it could have been a typing mistake. Moreover, [Grammarly seems to highlight this as well](https://ibb.co/V2LL6fZ).

You could also (perhaps) cover this idea by using the common idiom, "*[No use crying over spilt milk](https://www.bloomsbury-international.com/student-ezone/idiom-of-the-week/1371-its-no-use-crying-over-spilt-milk/#:%7E:text=You%20should%20not%20get%20upset,at%20something%20bad%20which%20happened.)*".

Comment: Your advice makes sense. I'm going to split the sentence into two sentences, as you suggested. You're right about the impact.